# Powershell in c# and permissions

Tags: powershell, windows-services, localsystem

I am running PowerShell scripts from a Windows service running as SYSTEM account. To increase rights I am letting users select a user that I later impersonate the whole thread as using LogonUser method.

This works so that I can access network drives and when I try to print the current user in PowerShell that works too.

But I have a case when it does not work:

One example is a user trying to load Exchange snapin and run cmdlet: Get-MailboxPermission

Then he get error: The term 'Get-MailboxPermission' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. The term 'Get-MailboxPermission' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I am guessing that this is permissions issue and I wonder if there is anything else that needs to be changed to RunSpace etc to get the increased permissions? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which PowerShell version?

Looks like you don't have the exchange snapin added. Try running this command before:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
```

or, via code, in the runspace initialization, use this code:

```
RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
myRunSpace.Open(rsConfig);
```

read this article for additional info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb332449(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: The script works when running it manually - but not when loaded in the service context (even though it is impersonated).

Comment: Have you tried to run the command i wrote *before* the other commands?