# Get-MailboxPermissions cmdlet not working/recognised

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I have been trying to use the Get-MailboxPermission cmdlet to run a report on all my mailboxes. I have run this piece of code (many times)

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://Exchange Server/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session
```

Which has given me othe exchange cmdlets, like Get-Mailbox. The message I receive when trying to run the command is as below

```
Get-MailboxPermission : The term 'Get-MailboxPermission' is not recognized 

as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MailboxPermission
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MailboxPermission:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12748293/419

Comment: Not sure which RBAC role this cmdlet is associated with, but when you do that Import-PSSession, you'll get a module of functions customized to the RBAC roles you belong to.  If you're not in an RBAC role that allows viewing those permission you won't have that cmdlet available.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to enable exchange functionality:

```
add-pssnapin *exchange* -erroraction SilentlyContinue
```

Then use the Get-Mailbox command.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I did not have the correct permissions to get these cmdlets, thanks to mjolinor for pointing me in the right direction (dont know why i didnt think about that in the first place).

> Not sure which RBAC role this cmdlet is associated with, but when you
>   do that Import-PSSession, you'll get a module of functions customized
>   to the RBAC roles you belong to. If you're not in an RBAC role that
>   allows viewing those permission you won't have that cmdlet available.
>   –  mjolinor 9 hours ago